# How to implement Logout functionality for Facebook graph API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, logout

I implemented Facebook Graph API in my iPhone App and I successfully post it in a wall. But each time I end my application and come back it stores my credentials (in Safari I guess as a cookie). It asks my permission with my previous credentials. But at this point I want my Facebook API should prompt for a new username and password login for requesting permission. In simple I want to logout of my Facebook when i select a button in my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you log in to facebook in the first place? If you are using facebook iOS SDK, you just basically have to call `[facebook logout:self];`. Otherwise if you're implementing Graph API yourself you just need to clear out your cookies and delete your access token.

Comment: you can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852515/how-to-clear-cookies-from-nshttpcookiestorage-more-then-once

Comment: I can successfully log out from application. But safari remembers me. So I want totally logout from both my application and safari. How can I do it?

Comment: @Burak they have different cookies. You can't logout from the app and safari from the app.

Comment: Ok, then how can I login with different user?

Comment: The same way you previously log in.

Answer (score 2):

```
fbGraph.accessToken = nil;
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString *domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are call the facebook button  at that method last line u wil write  this method   [facebook logout]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
        {
            [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
```

These codes are enough to implement logout functionality.

Its working perfectly on my app.